# ipython notebook on boot2docker not saved

Tags: ipython, boot2docker

I'm running ipython notebook from Boot2Docker.  I created new notebook and saved them before shutting it down.  But when I run docker again, all changes have been lost.  it must be some very simple steps that I have missed but I can't find any info by googling.

It's how to start the boot2docker:

```
bash-3.2$ /usr/local/bin/boot2docker init 
Virtual machine boot2docker-vm already exists
bash-3.2$ /usr/local/bin/boot2docker up 
Waiting for VM and Docker daemon to start...
```

And it's how to stop it.

```
boot2docker down
```

Comment: What exactly are the commands that you use for that? Could you give us some more information, please? Do you use volumes? `docker run` would create a new container which will be empty whereas `docker start` will start an existing one which has been shut down before (and which is probably not empty). Maybe that is your issue?

Comment: just edited the original post

Answer (score 0):

In your question you only describe how you start/stop `boot2docker`. But you are saying nothing about your container.

Assuming you start the [ipython/notebook](https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/ipython/notebook/) container via the following command:

```
docker run --name mycontainer -d -p 443:8888 -e "PASSWORD=MakeAPassword" ipython/notebook
```

Then after a `boot2docker` restart you could simply start the container previously created with:

```
docker start mycontainer
```

In that case all the data is back.

Of course when you issue a new `docker run` command like the first one, you get a fresh container and your data is not there.

When you need to access old data, just execute `docker ps -a` and see what stopped *ipython/notebook* containers are there. You can just start an old one to access its data (unless you did not do a *boot2docker reset* meanwhile).